# A Program for Simulating the Rolling of 2 Dice in C (How to fix my incorrect output?)

Tags: c, arrays, random, dice

I have to roll two dice 36,000 times and use a one-dimensional array to tally the number of times each number appears(2-12, with 7 being the most frequent sum and 2 and 12 the least frequent sums). My output just comes out with the whole table being 0's. What am I doing wrong?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int diceRoll(int die1, int die2, int tally[]);

int main(void) {

  int x;
  int y;
  int z[13] = {0};
  int sums = diceRoll(x, y, z);

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
  {
     printf("%3d%12d\n", i,sums);
     sums += sums;
  }
  printf( "\nTotal number of rolls is %d",sums );
  return 0;
}

int diceRoll(int die1, int die2, int tally[]) {   

  for(int i = 1; i <= 36000; i++) {
      die1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
      die2 = 1 + rand() % 6; 
      tally[die1 + die2]++;
  }
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: The `diceRoll()` function should be defined (and declared) to return `void` and the `return 0;` line should be removed (or replaced by `return;`, but removal is better).  That also means you'd change the call and not assign it to `sums`, which you'd initialize to `0`.

Comment: You're also calling `srand()` after you've generated all the 'random' numbers — so you'll get the same answer every time.  You need to call `srand()` once, and do so before you use `rand()`.

Comment: There is no real reason that diceRoll should have the die1 and die2 parameters. These variables are just local variables to the diceRoll function.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected a few lines of code:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
{
   printf("%3d%12d\n", i,z[i]);
   sums += z[i];
}
printf( "\nTotal number of rolls is %d\n",sums );
```

## Output

```
  2         989
  3        2009
  4        3052
  5        4091
  6        4983
  7        5965
  8        4897
  9        4048
 10        3066
 11        1965
 12         935
```